# Change RegistrationsController and SessionsController with Devise in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

I am using Devise in my application and I have to change the RegistrationController and SessionsController because I've done a before_action in application_controller and I wanna skip this before_action in these controllers, but I can't find them because they doesn't appear in RubyMine. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you want to change in RegistrationsConroller or SessionsController?  You can easily write your own controller and it will override Devise.

Comment: I just wanna put the skip_before_action in those controllers